# Unreal Engine: Rotation not working

Tags: animation, rotation, unreal-engine4

I am working with unreal engine and doing the cinematic tutorial from their website. However, after I selected the intro animation for the Grunt, when I rotated it, it would fly off the screen instead of rotating. I tried shutting down my computer and reopening the project but that didn't work either. Please Help. I have a video from my screen [here.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5-VsXhBBBuZV3Y5ZGgyQkJtR3M/view)

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some bugs that appear sometime. I also had this problem, when I was at UE4.16. Changing rotation manually from details panel helped me.

Answer (score 2):

I expect the rotation was in global space rather than local/object space.  Either that or that Grunt model is not at origin.